# NTDDI_VERSION setting conflicts with _WIN32_WINNT setting

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

With VS2010 I have this error:

```
error C1189: #error :  NTDDI_VERSION setting conflicts with _WIN32_WINNT setting
```

in StdAfx.h is use:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
```

and in my other source my.cpp i use:

```
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000000
```

How I can solve that?

Comment: The best is to let Microsoft's headers figure out these symbols after setting _WIN32_WINNT. You have done the opposite.

Comment: What's with all the hard-coded hex values in both the question and the answers?  There are named constants for all these values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000000
```

That is Vista.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
```

That is Server 2003.

And so these versions are indeed conflicting. If you want to support Vista and up you'll need:

```
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000000 
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
```

If you want Server 2003 and up then you use:

```
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x05020000
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
```

Note that the `NTDDI_VERSION` define can also specify service packs. So if you want Vista SP1 and up then you use:

```
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000100 
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
```

As a general rule you want to set these defines to the value corresponding to the minimum version that you wish to support.

Rather than using these magic constants, you should write, for example:

```
#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_VISTA 
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
```

For more details refer to MSDN: [Using the Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx).

Comment: i use windows 7 and windows 8 so for this windows what setting i must use? thank you

Comment: @user2997361 you'll want to define `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7` ONLY do not define the other macro, the SDK will do it for you.

Comment: You should use the minimum version that you wish the program to run on. Usually that is determined by being the minimum version that has all the functions that you wish to call.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan a reminder that the define [is only a helper, it is not guaranteed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4769808/332733) to work as advertised.

Comment: Why are you telling him to use magic numbers?  There are named constants well documented.

Comment: @CareyGregory I was just following what was written in the question. I agree that the named values are far better. Is my updated answer better?

Comment: Except for that you can't write the named values, because they are defined in `SDKDDKVer.h` and you need to have defined `_WIN32_WINNT` **before** you include `SDKDDKVer.h`. I love how they designed that.

Comment: @MicroVirus: _"you need to have defined `_WIN32_WINNT` before you include `SDKDDKVer.h`"_  So what? `#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA`, (or whatever), **before** `_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA` itself is defined is absolutely fine, as long as the definition for `_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA` has come into scope by the time the compiler needs to **evaluate** `_WIN32_WINNT`, (which is normally the case).

Comment: The MSDN link in this answer now redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers?redirectedfrom=MSDN - but I can't edit it in because the queue is full right now.

Answer (score 2):

`NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000000` is Windows Vista, so you need `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600`.

MSDN has the details you need [right here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers?redirectedfrom=MSDN).